# FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever Efficient loading

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm using the FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever to get image and loading them in imageView in listView,however it takes 6-7 seconds to load the list.Is there a efficient way I can load quickly by updating the following code?

```
  FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
                mmr.setDataSource(con, Uri.parse(image_url));
                Bitmap b = mmr.getFrameAtTime(2000000, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);

                //Log.e(TAG,"bitmap using FFMpeg is "+scaledBitmap);
                Log.e(TAG, "Size of NEW bitmap is " + p.getByteCount());
                holder.Img.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC instead of OPTION_CLOSEST will be faster but not as accurate

Comment: It does improve for sure, but can I improve it more by any other alternative??